# Why is my micrometer gauge only be executed once after application startup?

Tags: database, spring-boot, monitoring, aop, micrometer

i want to implement a micrometer gauge, to monitor the amount of records in my database. so I created an aspect with `spring-boot-starter-aop` which is executed after my service methods are getting called.

Aspect:

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class ContactAmountAspect {

  @Autowired
  ContactRepository contactRepository;

  @Autowired
  MeterRegistry registry;

  @AfterReturning(value = "execution(* mypackage.ContactService.*(..))")
  public void monitorContactAmount() {
    Gauge
        .builder("contacts.amount", contactRepository.findAll(), List::size)
        .register(registry);
    log.info("Amount of contacts in database: {}", contactRepository.findAll().size());
  }
}
```

On the `/prometheus` endpoint I only see the amount of contacts on the first call after the application startup.
If I now call my POST rest endpoint and add a contact to my database, only my `log.info` prints out the new amount of contacts, but my gauge does nothing.
Order:

```
1. App Startup (let's say with 1 contact in DB)
2. Call Rest Endpoint "getAllContacts"
3. My AOP method starts
4. The gauge monitors contact amount of 1
5. the logger logs contact amount of 1
6. Call Rest Endpoint "postOneContact"
7. My AOP method starts
8. The gauge does nothing or monitors still the amount of 1
9. the logger logs contact amount of 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Or is there another way to monitor the amount of records in a database table???*

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to register a new metric with the same ID. A meter is uniquely identified by its combination of name and tags. If you register meters having the same ID multiple times, the first registration only will work and the subsequent registrations will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the problem is incorrect initialization of Gauge metric. You should declare this metric like that:

```
    Gauge
        .builder("contacts.amount", contactRepository, ContactRepository::count)
        .register(registry);
```

This code work for me!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the gauge builder doesn't work.
instead I have to use this:

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class AspectConfig {

  @Autowired
  ContactRepository contactRepository;

  AtomicInteger amount = new AtomicInteger(0);

  @AfterReturning("execution(* mypackage.ContactService.*(..))")
  public void monitorContactAmount() {
    Metrics.gauge("database.contacts.amount", amount);
    amount.set(contactRepository.findAll().size());
    log.info("Monitoring amount of contacts in database: {}", contactRepository.findAll().size());
  }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think there’s anything wrong with the builder. The problem was that you were trying to register a new metric each time, rather than registering it once with a supplier that calls findAll each time it’s called and returns the size of the result

Comment: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_manually_incrementing_or_decrementing_a_gauge